# Why isnt git ignoring my sub directory?

Tags: windows, git, gitignore

my .gitignore file

```
ext/templates_c
```

my git status call

```
D:\Development\online\site\newsite>git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   ext/pages/config.php
#       modified:   ext/templates_c/60a4cccd667e8b1e3a702b2a2c9108f056837adc.file.pages.html.php
#       modified:   ext/templates_c/fd38ffaa13c6f4c29772bec22cad5aebb1d4d7f6.file.form.html.php
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Have I done something really stupid?

Why isnt git ignoring the files in ext/templates_c

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `git status` shows files in your "ignored" subdirectory as "modified" means that those files are already being tracked by `git`. Because of this, simply adding the directory to `.gitignore` is not sufficient to get those files ignored (although new files in that directory will properly be ignored). You need to do a `git rm --cached <file>` for each of the files in that directory that are currently tracked.

Answer (score 0):

As I was writing this I discovered that

```
 ext/templates_c
```

does not work but

```
ext\templates_c
```

does.

So you need to use windows slashes.